# Use type of concrete implementation in abstract base class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstract-class

Is there any way to do what I want here?

The base class is defined as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<TExists>
    where TExists : BaseExists
{
    // needs to be overridden by child
    protected abstract bool Exists(TExists existsData, out /*typeof(this)*/ existingElement); // <- how to have the concrete type here?

    // static method to be invoked without any need of an instance
    public static bool Exists(TExists existsData, out /*typeof(this)*/ existingElement)
    {
        var temp; // <-- how to set the type here?

        // create a concrete instance
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(???);

        // call the concrete implementation
        if(instance.Exists(existsData, out temp))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And here we have some concrete implementation:

```
public class ChildClass : BaseClass<ChildClassExists>
{
    protected override bool Exists(ChildClassExists exists, out ChildClass existingElement)
    {
        // do child-related things here
    }
}
```

At the end I want to use it like

```
ChildClass existing;    
if(ChildClass.Exists(new ChildClassExists(), out existing)){
    // do things here with the existing element of type 'ChildClass'
}
```

because I don't need an instance here (this is hidden inside the base class implementation of Exists).

**Update #1**

As implemented like in InBetweens first answer I now have:

```
public static bool Exists<T>(TExists existsModel, out T existingEntityModel)
    where T : BaseClass<TExists>
{
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    return instance.ExistsInternal(existsModel, out existingEntityModel);
}

protected abstract bool ExistsInternal<T>(TExists createModel, out T existingEntityModel)
    where T : BaseClass<TExists>;
```

But this will throw an error inside a concrete implementation of the ExistsInternal method

> Cannot convert source type 'ChildClass' to target type 'T'

in override

```
protected override bool ExistsInternal<T>(ChildClassExists existsData, out T existingElement)
{
    existingElement = new ChildClass(); // <-- here the error is thrown
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to add another generic parameter (`TConcrete`). But overall, problem implies a bad design. Also, instead of `Activator.CreateInstance()`, you'll be able to do `new TConcrete()` (assuming you'll be able to add the `new()` constraint)

Comment: Have you tried `out TExists existingElement` and `TExists temp;` ?

Comment: @FabioLuz: `TExists` is the base-type of the object containing the data for the exists-check and not the type of the object that should be returned-

Comment: @haim770: Why is this bad design? I must ensure to have an `Exists` for each concrete implementation but there is no need to create an instance in order to call it. On the other hand, what woul be a better workaround?

Comment: `public static bool Exists<T>(TExists existsData, out T existingElement) where T: BaseClass<TExists>`?

Answer (score 2):

Just add a new generic parameter in the `Exists` method. This type will be inferred by the compiler so there is no real impact in usability:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<TExists> where TExists : BaseExists
{
    // needs to be overridden by child
    protected abstract bool InternalExistsCheck<T>(TExists existsData, out T existingElement) where T : BaseClass<TExists>, new();

    // static method to be invoked without any need of an instance
    public static bool Exists<T>(TExists existsData, out T existingElement) where T : BaseClass<TExists>, new()
    {
        T temp; // <-- how to set the type here?
        existingElement = null;

        // create a concrete instance
        var instance = new T();

        // call the concrete implementation
        if (instance.InternalExistsCheck(existsData, out temp))
        {
            existingElement = temp;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that if you don't change the protected `Exists` method, you'll get an ambigous call compile time error (VS 2013).

Now, its perfectly fine to do:

```
public class ChildClass : BaseClass<ChildClassExists>
{
    protected override bool InternalExistsCheck<T>(ChildClassExists exists, out T existingElement)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

and

```
ChildClass existing;

if (ChildClass.Exists(new ChildClassExists(), out existing))
{
     // do things here with the existing element of type 'ChildClass'
}
```

*UPDATE*

Adressing your concern about not being able to assign a `ChildInstance` to `existing` in the overriden `ChildClass.InternalExistsCheck(,)`, yes you can by simply doing:

```
existing = new T();
```

If `T` is `ChildClass` (inferred by the compiler) then you will be creating a `ChildClass` instance. Bear in mind though that you are getting a `BaseClass<ChildExists>` typed reference, not a `ChildClass` one.

If you absolutely need a `ChildClass` typed reference then there is a workaround (if you need to do this, its probably because generics is not the right tool for you):

```
var childClassTypedReference = (object)existing as ChildClass.
```

Do realize that the whole solution is not as type safe as you'd maybe wish; you *must* consider the possibility of`existing` not being a `ChildClass` typed reference (and therefore `childClassTypedReference` being `null`). There is nothing preventing `existing` from being *any* type extending `BaseClass<ChildExists>`.

I don't have the whole picture of your code but I really think you are misusing generics here. I think a non generic approach with an `IExists` interface dependency would be a much cleaner approach.

Comment: `default(T)` would always return `null` in this case and you'll get an NRE in the next line

Comment: @haim7770: yeah, its `new T()`. Wasn't thinking right :p Thanks

Comment: I still have problems with the `out` parameter of type `T` which cannot be set in `ChildClass`s override of `InternalExistsCheck`. Don't see what I am missing.

Comment: @KingKerosin remember that you have to set a value to the out parameter before the return of the method

Comment: @KingKerosin You can not assign `ChildClass` typed instances to `T` because the type of `T` is really `BaseClass<ChildExists>`. C# does not admit type variance in overriden methods (it's not a generics limitation). You *could* circumvent this abusing the generics system but it's not worth the headache.

Comment: @KingKerosin see update to my answer addressing your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the comments/answers I came up with the following solution which perfectly fits my needs.

1 Added a new (non-generic) base-class `BaseClass`

2 Let generic base inherit from non-generic

```
public abstract class BaseClass<TExists> : BaseClass
{
}
```

3 Setup `abstract` and `static` methods in `BaseClass<TExists>`

```
// abstract to be overriden by child-classes
protected abstract BaseClass ExistsInternal(TExists existsModel);

public static bool Exists<T>(TExists existsModel, out T existing) where T : BaseClass<TExists>
{
    // create a new instance of the concrete child
    var instance = (T) Activator.CreateInstance<T>;

    // set the out parameter (can be null)
    existing = instance.ExistsInternal(existsModel) as T;

    // return if already existing
    return existing!= null;
}
```

4 Implement override in child-classes

```
protected override BaseClass ExistsInternal(ChildClassExists existsModel)
{
    // check for existing
    var existing = ...; // do child-class dependend stuff

    // return concrete instance or null
    return existing != null ? new ChildClass(existing) : null;
}
```

5 Call it (with types inferred from usage through `ChildClass`)

```
ChildClass childClass;
if (ChildClass.Exists(childClassExists, out childClass))
{
    // do things with existing childClass
}
```

6 Say thanks to InBetween and haim7770

> @InBetween, @haim7770 -> Thank you! ;)